# Find rows that partially match conditions in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to query for rows in a table that match all the conditions or a subset of them, defining the minimum size for that subset?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <condition 1> AND <condition 2> AND ... AND <condition 9>
```

Given the 9 conditions, can I find all rows that match at least 6 of them? Also - can I know how many of the conditions each row matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        case when <condition1> then 1 else 0 end
        + case when <condition2> then 1 else 0 end
        . . . 
        + case when <conditionN> then 1 else 0 end as match_count
    from your_table t
) where match_count >= 6;
```

The above solution is a standard one and will work on most of the databases.
In Postgres, since output of conditions are boolean and booleans can be [casted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html) into int (true - 1 and false - 0) using `<condition>::int`, the same solution can be rewritten as:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        <condition1>::int 
        + <condition2>::int
        + ...
        + <conditionN>::int as match_count
    from your_table t
) where match_count >= 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gurv has exactly the right approach.  However, it can be "simplified" for Postgres.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ((<condition 1>):int +
       (<condition 2>)::int +
       . . . 
      ) >= 6 -- or whatever
```